# Why does my XML code not validate from Internet Explorer?

Tags: xml, internet-explorer

I have generated XML code from a java class, when i open it in internet explorer it works great. Then when i try copy the text from internet explorer into a validator to compare with a schema it comes up with an  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException error. When i copy the code from chrome into validator it works great. How do i fix this?

```
My XML code:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    -<BusStops>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>0100BRP90336</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>The Centre</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Bristol City Centre</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName>Bristol</ParentLocalityName>

    <Latitude>51.4543379612</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-2.5978824115</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>0170SGA56570</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>UWE Entrance North</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Abbey Wood</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>51.50419145</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-2.549547265</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>079073001Z</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Bus Station Express Lounge</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Middlesbrough</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>54.5760020508</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-1.2391798779</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>0800COC31523</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Bus Station</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Newquay</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>50.4130339395</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-5.0856695446</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>0800COC56586</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Bus Station</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Camborne</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>50.2132677521</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-5.2974299693</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>0800COD40027</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>St Claire's</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Penzance</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>50.1178632763</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-5.5429319148</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>0800COD40491</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Railway Station</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>St Erth</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>50.17113042</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-5.4447567103</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>

   -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>227000010790</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Tesco</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Scunthorpe</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>53.5900597528</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-0.6954877689</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>2290YHA01586</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Hull Interchange</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Hull</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>53.7442912914</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-0.3483033625</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>2500918</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>University Underpass</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Lancaster University</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>54.0102461687</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-2.7854986348</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>2500JB17</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Bus Station</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Preston City Centre</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName>Preston</ParentLocalityName>

    <Latitude>53.7615429712</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-2.6961132517</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>260003731</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>ASDA Petrol Station</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Fosse Park</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>52.5989980284</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-1.1777495222</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>260007240</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Holywell Way</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Loughborough</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>52.7632692942</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-1.2430689523</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>

    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>490016736W</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Victoria Coach Station Arrivals</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Victoria</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName>London</ParentLocalityName>

    <Latitude>51.4934345348</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-0.1490086681</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>5210ANZ12808</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Ferry Terminal</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Pembroke Dock</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>51.6961675232</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-4.9522760255</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>5220AWK65859</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Bus Station </CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Carmarthen</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>51.8554494637</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-4.3084744349</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>5230AWC53153</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Pioneer</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Lampeter</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>52.1092562139</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-4.074132457</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>5230AWD71087</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>University Campus Penglais</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Penglais</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>52.4177900287</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-4.065937127</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>5230WDB25330</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Bus Station</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Aberystwyth</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>52.4144426154</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-4.0809416231</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>5230WDB48199</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Pioneer</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Lampeter</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>52.1093665968</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-4.0745026926</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>5310WDB47981</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Queensway</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Newport</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>51.5889028696</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-2.9992653102</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>5710WDB48382</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Kingsway</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Cardiff</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>51.4840881799</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.1788570039</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>5810WDB48071</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Bus Station Stand C</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Swansea</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>51.617243437</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.9462082354</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>60903826</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Buchanan Bus Station</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Glasgow</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>55.8651960292</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-4.2503286787</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>61601719</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Town Centre stances</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Cumbernauld</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>55.9467703584</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.9907153307</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>6200600739</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Bus Station</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Edinburgh</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>55.955315382</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.192059531</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>639070021</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Union Square Bus Station</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Aberdeen</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>57.1445763077</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-2.0963111958</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>6400L00040</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Bus Station</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Dundee City Centre</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName>Dundee</ParentLocalityName>

    <Latitude>56.4630579441</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-2.9659684135</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>64802054</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Park and Ride</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Broxden</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName>Perth</ParentLocalityName>

    <Latitude>56.386756734</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.4800221149</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>6500D1064</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Park and Ride</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Ferrytoll</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>56.0225813799</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.4062755617</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>6500D1605</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Bus Station</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Dunfermline</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>56.0722848463</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.4617448581</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>6500D1701</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Park and Ride</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Halbeath</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName>Dunfermline</ParentLocalityName>

    <Latitude>56.0840262551</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.3912536513</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>66901001017</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Asda</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Falkirk</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>56.0005777292</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.7870320137</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>66901001019</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>St Andrew`s Church</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Falkirk</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>56.0004700396</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.7864015998</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>9100STPMEG</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>London St Pancras Megabusplus</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>St Pancras</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName>London</ParentLocalityName>

    <Latitude>51.5306153552</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-0.1255278085</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>66004000033</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Allan Park South Church</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Stirling</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>56.1170355497</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.9382449181</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>66004890065</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Argyll Avenue</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Stirling</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>56.1244909497</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.9315889902</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>66004481015</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Linden Avenue</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Stirling</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>56.1110354722</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.9305930859</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>66004000039</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Murray Place</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Stirling</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>56.1194615081</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.9371282257</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>66004000043</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Railway Station</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Stirling</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>56.1204940089</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.9366170649</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>6200243380</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>North St David Street</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Edinburgh</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>55.9550130307</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.1945167932</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>6200206485</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Princes Mall</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Edinburgh</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>55.9531738427</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.1905042482</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>6200206165</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Princes Street</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Edinburgh</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>55.9506985183</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-3.2048095889</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>60903901</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Scotland Street</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Glasgow</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>55.849666387</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-4.2659346227</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>60903904</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Shields Road</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Glasgow</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>55.8499104556</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-4.2746241674</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>609093</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Shuttle Street</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Glasgow</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>55.8605228656</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-4.2409492822</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>60903844</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>St Andrews Square</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Glasgow</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>55.8549094588</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-4.2436939603</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>60903539</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>St Enoch shopping centre</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Glasgow</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>55.8560567892</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-4.2517336817</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>639080008</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Aberdeen Railway Station</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Aberdeen</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>57.1437934462</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-2.0980112638</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>


    -<BusStopDetails>

    <AtcoCode>9300ABA</AtcoCode>

    <CommonName>Aberdeen Ferry Terminal</CommonName>

    <LocalityName>Aberdeen</LocalityName>

    <ParentLocalityName/>

    <Latitude>57.1447953603</Latitude>

    <Longitude>-2.0917010936</Longitude>

    </BusStopDetails>

    </BusStops>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice to you would be to not copy the XML from the actual Internet Explorer view.  If you look closely, you'll notice that IE has modified some of the tags by adding a dash to them, e.g.

```
-<BusStops>
-<BusStopDetails>
```

A better bet would be to either save the XML in IE and open that saved file in Chrome, or just open the export from Java directly in Chrome.

Comment: The problem is that it is an assignment meaning i cant control what Browser they use when mark. Is there no way of saving the document into Chrome from a java program?

Comment: I'm confused now.  I thought the XML were _output_ from your Java program, and you needed to import it.  In any case, just tell your users to save as XML.  Copying such a large file, even if it were formatted correctly, is time costly and error prone.

Comment: I save my file to a specific folder but is there any code which could be put in the saving aspect of the xml which would save it as a chrome file or will it always be IE cause its windows? :D

Comment: Yes the XML is output from a java program converting a csv into it. I have saved it to my specific folder to be opened and used to validate.

Comment: Again, I don't follow you.  The file should be saved as XML text.  The format should not be a function of the browser.

Comment: Yes of course. But im guessing XML's assigned Browser when you open it is always gonna be IE?

Comment: OK now I understand your question.  Have a look [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/144982-how-change-default-xml-editor.html) if you want to associate Chrome as the default editor for XML.  But keep in mind some of your users may not have Chrome.